How to determine where a global variable is set in JavaScript
I'm working inside a  function and according to the developer tools in Chrome and Firefox there's a global variable that appears to have the data that I need.  However, I don't know where it's coming from and hence am afraid to rely on it.  Is there a way to determine where it's declared and set in the developer tools in any browser?  I have Edge (regular and canary), Chrome (regular and canary), multiple versions of Firefox, Brave, and Vivaldi.

In a browser, everything in window is global. In Node.js, globals go in global, eg "global.myGlobal = ..."

And to those who say "Don't use global variables!" it's definitely okay to use global const fields. And if you are just trying to hack something together for a 1 off, using global variables can be a shortcut

@ControlAltDel I think your disctinction of global const fields is useful.  I was able to do a brute force search and find where my global variable was introduced in less than an hour, although it was a very widely used variable name in my website and could have taken many hours to find.  It's not seeming that any of browser's developer tools will really show you this though.  Although, they do separate the global variables, which is useful.

You would need a tool for that, but definitely not in the bowser. probably in your IDE by a static scanner tool or by an AI scanning your files. or some CLI tool. but this isn't a "browser thing" you could see in the devtools.

All JavaScript global variables reside within the heap as they are available to all scope blocks (unless shadowed)

The question asks how to find out where the variable is defined within the code, not where it is stored.
